# Restrict access to website

Tags: html, authorization

All,

I have developed an internal website for a firm and then need to restrict access to only the internal workers. i.e. connected to their own wireless network. For anyone outside the network, the website should not open up at all. For those in the network, username/password should be prompted?

How can I:
1 > Check for the access depending on IP address?
2 > Check for username/password prompt if IP address is valid?

Comment: We need more information: 1. what web server are you running. 2. where is the username/password stored?

Comment: More information as in ? Please be specific. Since I have never done this before, I don't know what would be needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to post my answer assuming you used apache.  You can do this but you need to generate the users/password file so have a look at the documentation for that.

```
<Location />
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from company.com
  Deny from all
  Require user someuser
  Require user someotheruser
</Location>
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have requirements *other* than protecting the site from users in the outside world, you don't need to do any form of authentication as the intranet site should be hosted on a server local to the intranet and with no form of connection to the outside world.

Comment: In other words, the website is *behind the firewall*, invisible to internet users.